# Cosa sono le "lastre d'archivio"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Che poi
>   un’impresa gentilizia – un nido d’api, col vocabolo *Uberius* al centro – pompeggiasse in cima al suo biglietto da
>   visita, nessuno di noi smise mai di considerarlo un abuso, a dispetto delle commendatizie che si affannava a
>   fornirgli la quercia dipinta, dalle radici come murene,
>   appesa in alto dietro il suo scrittoio. Singolare pianta,
>   davvero! Non protetta da vetro, ma da giustapposte **lastre d’archivio**, preventivamente nettate con acqua tiepida dalle macule e magagne di qualche ignoto defunto; e
>   si levava dal suolo con tale energia e abbondanza di
>   chiome da far temere che presto sarebbe evasa dall’effratta cornice per espandere liberamente i suoi cartigli
>   nell’aria.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa sono le "lastre d'archivio"? Ho cercato alle voci "lastra" e "archivio" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le ***lastre d'archivio*** non sono altro che pellicole fotografiche destinate alla radiologia ospedaliera riportanti esami radiologici fatti da pazienti ormai defunti.

Infatti l'autore descrive il fatto che esse venivano ripulite (nettate) con l'acqua tiepida dalle macchie (macule) e dalle risultanti malattie (magagne) di un qualche paziente passato a miglior vita.

Le lastre di quel periodo sono probabilmente di celluloide su cui veniva apposta una emulsione fotosensibile a base di sali di argento. Al giorno d'oggi è un prodotto di nicchia perché ormai soppiantata dall'avvento del digitale.

Comment: Vedo però che appare in molti siti web d'astronomia.

Comment: E ["di nicchia"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nicchia) significa che "è indirizzato a una nicchia di mercato"?

Comment: Esatto, ormai il digitale ha preso il sopravvento.

Comment: Quindi, si tratterebbe di pellicole fotografiche in generale?

Comment: Anche su [questo sito web](https://www.poesianonesa.it/bibliografia), quando si parla del libro intitolato *Paesaggi anauni*, le "lastre d'archivio" non sembrano essere materiale di radiologia medica.

Comment: Però nel contesto si fa riferimento a macule e magagne di qualche ignoto defunto, il che fa presumere che siano di tipo medico.

Comment: Vedo che l'accezione **2 b** di ["lastra" nel Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lastra/) è "sinonimo di *radiografia*". Tuttavia non avevo pensato che se potessero usare delle radiografie invece di un vetro per proteggere un dipinto.

Comment: Inizialmente le lastre radiografiche erano di vetro, poi è stato sostituito dalla celluloide e poi dal digitale.

Comment: Ma non erano di colore scuro?

Comment: No, la base era trasparente e veniva ricoperta di sali di argento che si impressionavano con l’esposizione alla luce, diventando scura o nera a seconda del livello di esposizione

Comment: Capisco, grazie.